# AWS Airflow inoperable after OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

I was running a DAG on AWS Managed Apache Airflow that was supposed to download data on the machine, move it to S3 and delete the local files afterwards. However, during the run I received `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`, causing the DAG to fail. The operation caused the machine to run out of disk space and now all DAGs would fail immediately after start without any log file being generated and I'm having hard time finding what to do in this situation. Ideally I could somehow clear the local files and make the Airflow operable again. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was to restart the MWAA instance by editing it. This wiped all local files and made the airflow operable again.

Comment: How did you do this?